# Unable to install Flash Debug Player on Fedora 19

Tags: linux, firefox, fedora, flash, debug

I'm trying to install Flash Debug Player in Fedora 19 x64.

I understand that Flash Debug Player is not available for x64 on Linux, so the way to go would be to install the i686 version, and then use `nspluginwrapper` for compatibility, but it just won't work.

I've followed [a guide](http://supervacuo.com/blog/2012/sep/25/installing-flash-player-content-debugger-on-fedora/) and others like it with minor variations, but Firefox then just acts as if flash wasn't installed at all, no errors whatsoever.

Has anyone made a successful installation on Fedora? Are there any logs or something I could check to see why exactly this is not loading the plugin?

Comment: AFAIK flash now has a 64 bit version

Comment: I'm talking about the debug version of it, I haven't seen a 64bit version of it.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. If you are desperate, a good workaround would be to run a 32 bit chroot.